# How to specify ID greater than <something> in the where clause?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gqlquery

Just recently tried something like the following in the appengine interactive console:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from django.utils import simplejson

class TestDb(db.Model):
    author = db.StringProperty()

def add(name):
    t = TestDb()
    t.author = name
    t.put()
#added some names...
lst = db.GqlQuery("Select * from TestDb")

print [(x.key().id(), x.author) for x in lst]
```

I know for fact that ID is not sequential, but I assume it will be ascending in order for every new record that comes in.

Now I want to put a condition whose SQL would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TestDb WHERE ID > 2
```

Is this possible via `GqlQuery()`?

Comment: Have you tried doing that? You should have no problem testing this.

Comment: And what did you get when you ran the code you posted?

Comment: i got all the entries for that list comprehension

Comment: Well, I really haven't used GQL, but if you can't use the query, you could add an if statement to the list comprehension without much of a performance hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatically assigned IDs are not guaranteed to be sequential, so if you want to rely on ordering your entities you should either assign IDs yourself (which I wouldn't recommend), or sort by another property (perhaps a creation timestamp?)

With that said, you can filter by ID using the special `__key__` property. See [Key Filters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Key_Filters).

Comment: can you write this in the where clause...?

Comment: Yes, I believe so: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference

Comment: the id needn't be sequential, but will the last record I "put" have a value greater than its corresponding value in the penultimate record entry...?

Comment: The only way that could be is if the record IDs are sequential, so no.

Comment: No, entities with smaller IDs may be created after entities with larger ones. @DanHolevoet 1 2 10 11 50 101

Comment: @NickJohnson I didn't say otherwise.

Comment: @DanHolevoet "1, 2, 10" is not sequential - but it still meets the requirement of each ID being greater than the ones that come before it.

Comment: @NickJohnson I was defining "sequential" as increasing (possibly non-consecutively). However, I guess that's only one possible interpretation of sequence (even if a common one). But we're arguing over semantics, the answer's still "No" regardless.